# Where clause to filter rows for Azure Stretch Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Currently stretch database in SQL Server 2016 moves the entire table to Azure. However, this [InfoQ article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/06/SQL-Server-Stretch) mentions an "archive row" mode for Stretch database that will allow you to filter which rows in a table to move to the cloud (ex. records before 2010). I haven't been able to find any official Microsoft documentation regarding this unreleased feature.

Can someone point me to an official source that says this is coming for RTM? I did find a French blog entry on MSDN mentioning it but nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documented now for the latest CTP release. See how to write a TVF that a filter predicate uses to define what is a cold row (that gets moved) in a table with a mix of hot & cold rows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613432.aspx